# for mongo, not able to create users other than admin with error command createUser requires authentication :

Tags: mongodb, security

This is the script I am using to create user accounts in MongoDB:

```
mongo <<EOF
use admin;
db.createUser({user:ram", pwd: "ram123!", roles:['root']});
db.createUser({user:"sam", pwd: "sam123!", roles:[{db:"config", role:'readWrite'}]});
EOF
```

This works for the creating first user, but not the second user. This is the error that is returned:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("f648b868-7863-4d5c-9912-e3e87b24f4e8") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.6
switched to db admin
Successfully added user: { "user" : "ram", "roles" : [ "root" ] }
uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1386:11
@(shell):1:1
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the different databases that are expected when creating the accounts. The first one, `ram` is created against the `admin` database. The second one, `sam` is expected to be made on the `config` database, but you're connected to `admin`, making this impossible.

In order to do this correctly, you need to first connect to the `config` database and run the script there for users who will have access to `config`.

Comment: how can i make my admin user "ram" create other users in other databases through the script?

Comment: and who is creating the user in config database in the above script? is it "Ram"

Comment: In your script you have `USE admin`. That ensures the database is `admin`. If you want to have accounts in other databases created, you'll need to switch to those DBs using an account that has a role allowing for account creation. You can use additional `USE {dbname}` commands to accomplish this. As for "who", it's the account you are running the script under. There is nothing in your script that disconnects and re-authenticates as `ram`.

Comment: can i disconnect and reauthenticate as 'ram' to create users in admin database?

Comment: It's your database and your script. You can do whatever you'd like

Comment: sry what i meant was can disconnecting and reauthenticating as 'ram' to create users in admin database through shell script is possible?  i am pretty new to scripting and mongo

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

After creating the first user on `admin` database (the user "ram", which you had created successfully) which can administrate users and roles (a ***user administrator***), you need to do these following steps to create other users:

**Shutdown the `mongod` instance, from the `mongo` shell:**

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer();
```

Exit the shell.

**Start the `mongod` again with the `auth` option:**

> The `--auth` option enables authorization to control user's access to
> database resources and operations. When authorization is enabled,
> MongoDB requires all clients to authenticate themselves first in order
> to determine the access for the client.

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath ...
```

From now onward, clients that connect to this instance must authenticate themselves as a MongoDB user. The clients can only perform actions as determined by their assigned roles.

**Connect to the instance from `mongo` shell:**

```
mongo --port 27017  --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "ram" -p "rams_password"
```

Now you have authenticated yourself as a ***user administrator***. So, you can create other users with various roles.

**Create additional users as needed, now (for example):**

```
use db2
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "db2User",
    pwd:  "db2_pass",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "db2" } ]
  }
)
```

This will create a user "db2User" which has the role "readWrite" on the database "db2". Note the `use db2` command before the `createUser()`; it means that the ***authentication database*** for this user is "db2". When this user needs to read or write data to the "db2" database he/she needs to authenticate against this database, like this from `mongo` shell:

```
mongo --port 27017  --authenticationDatabase "db2" -u "db2User" -p "db2_pass"
```

**Note that, your authentication database can be different from that of the database you specify in the `roles`**, for example:

```
use db2
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "mongoUser",
    pwd:  "mongo_pass",
    roles: [ { role: "read", db: "myDB" } ]
  }
)
```

**The Error:**

The error you are getting is because that you have not authenticated yourself as a ***user administrator***, before creating new users.

To understand this in detail, you need to get familiar with [MongoDB Security](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/) aspects of Authentication and Authorization.

Comment: thank u very much